# Wordpress site link leads to WAMP configuration page

Tags: wordpress, wampserver

I have a wordpress site on localhost.On clicking a few links such as About us/Contact Us, I get redirected to this page.Please help
[View snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Thdo.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: See [The need for Virtual Hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) site maybe shows your answer.

The problem is that you are running with a Wamp server and Wordpress may think that your root directory `localhost/` is the Wordpress' root directory instead of `localhost/wordpress/`.

Change the location with the tutorial from wordpress.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There should be problem of your `.htaccess` file in your root folder `www/WordPress`.

Rename your .htaccess to .htaccess-bak first.

Try to update your permalink from Setting->Permalink section. Try to change permalink from default to post and save it.

That might solve your problem.

The problem is in the RewriteBase rule so you can try this solution if above is not worked. Please check this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/all-secondary-pages-redirecting-to-wamp-server-file-page-wp/202676/2)

Hope this will be helpful for you. Thanks.